# Custom page layout is not available on sub-sites

Tags: page-layout, publishing-page

I have a custom page layout in the root site (Created by SPD and published/approved). I can create pages with this layout in the root site but in the deeper sub-sites in pages library, when i click create new page, i cannot see my custom page layout?

How can i see my custom layout in all sub-sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to goto site actions -> site settings -> page layouts and site templates -> then their is a radio subsites can use any site templates